# Loading Mathematical Programming System files

Tags: r, linear-programming

I'm trying to load an MPS file from [netlib](http://www.netlib.org/lp/data/) to `RStudio`.

I use `[Rglpk][2]` library to load `25fv47.MPS`:

> `Rglpk_read_file("/MPS/25fv47.txt", 
>   type = c("MPS_fixed"),
>   ignore_first_row = FALSE, 
>   verbose = FALSE)`

but it crashes RStudio.
[image]

How can I load these files?

Comment: Explain how you did preprocess the file (which you probably did reading those filenames).

Comment: I unpacked it and then load it in R

Comment: *unpacked*....?